# Using Resharper to compile the source cant hit the breakpoint

Tags: resharper

When I use Resharper to compile my source that I always cant hit the breakpoint and the Visual Studio say that

The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version.

I must click the rebuild button to rebuild the source to hit it.

Can anyone give me some way to make the resharper to build the source well?

I don't want to do some step when I want to run app than press F5.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a result of perceived differences between the source code and compiled debugging symbols. I'm not sure if this will help, but you could try allowing slightly different source code when debugging. Untick the option as shown...

Tools > Options > Debugging

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it cant any help for resharper use the old dll.